# android Add Badge on Expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, badge

I don't know how we can add Badge in `ExpandableListView`.
I searched some keywords but no result talk about this. So I post picture and want to know this may occur?
Thanks for supports.

[image: http://i905.photobucket.com/albums/ac258/phamthangnd/Untitled_zpse9943367.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two layout xml files for Group and Child views respectively - For example, *group_layout.xml* and *child_layout.xml* These layouts are inflated and used in the custom ExpandableListAdapter as shown below.

For Information please Check the [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551882/how-to-customize-views-of-expandablelist)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solotion for this example:

**bg_badge.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ff2233" />

</shape>
```

**tab_indicator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNumberBadge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_badge"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_ask" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_color"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_child.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutmain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_badge_text"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitleSearch1"
            style="@style/TextSizeNormalFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitleSearch2"
            style="@style/TextSizeNormalFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitleSearch3"
            style="@style/TextSizeNormalFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_badge_text"
        style="@style/TextBadgeNumber"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/newtext"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_name"
        style="@style/TextSizeNormalFont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_badge_number"
        style="@style/TextBadgeNumber"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/badge_number"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope help someone.

Screenshot: http://i905.photobucket.com/albums/ac258/phamthangnd/Untitled_zps18aa246f.png